# How to set Under Line For Header for UITableview cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have made one demo which is working fine.
I got stuck at one point.

## Image

[image]

## Question

1)How to make this type of functionality Header and bellow header state ,date and comments ?

2)How can I set underline "see it is light grey colour" between cell and header?

Comment: Create your custom view and return that view in `viewForHeaderInSection` method of `UITableViewDelegate`.

Comment: @NiravD but he wants it for every cell

Comment: No I want only from header and cell,not every cell

Comment: I did self.tableview.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone; for hide line for cell

Comment: @NiravD Lol :) Yes I have to read

Answer (score 0):

1.You can return header view in this function of `UITableViewDelegate`.

```
optional public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? 
// custom view for header. will be adjusted to default or specified header height
```

2.You can add that line programmatically or try to set the style of table view to `Plain`.

Comment: Please ,give me in objective c

Answer (score 0):

Plase Make Custom view in viewForHeaderInSection

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
/// create your custom view//
return customView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a custom view however you want (like in image you posted)

2.Return that view as header for section in this method

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this delegate method.

```
   -(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    UIView *headerView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, HEADER_H)];
         UIView *lineView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, HEADER_H-2, tableView.frame.size.width, 1)];
        lineView.backgroundColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];

        [headerView addSubview:lineView];

        return headerView;
 }
```